# Google App Engine: Disable session middleware for services

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gae-module

I have an app running with session middleware to handle logged on users. This is configured in appengine_config.py like this:

```
import datetime
from gaesessions import SessionMiddleware
import jinja2
# Add session middleware
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    app = SessionMiddleware(app, cookie_key="Yqjo13XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", lifetime=datetime.timedelta(minutes=30), no_datastore=True, cookie_only_threshold=0)
    return app
```

I now created a service to handle the cronjob requests but I don't want that to load the session middleware. Is there a way to have the service, located in a separate dir but with it's cronservice.yaml in the app root directory, to ignore the settings in the appengine_config.py? Those are only meant for the default app, the web UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my app is split up in several services I have my frontend controllers in a subdir frontend/controllers so I check the router info for it and if needed import the modules:

```
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
# If frontend add session middleware
if 'frontend' in str(app.router):
    # Setup GAE sessions
    import datetime
    from gaesessions import SessionMiddleware
    import jinja2
    app = SessionMiddleware(app, cookie_key="XXXXX", lifetime=datetime.timedelta(minutes=30), no_datastore=True, cookie_only_threshold=0)

return app
```

When this hits the **str(app.router)** contains